# How to quickly bin data in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this hundreds of thousands of rows. What I want is for every 10 rows, I want to take its average or bin it. I can implement this running a for loop, but this will take a very long time. Is there a more direct way?

Comment: So if you have a 1000 row vector `data`, you want a 100 row vector `result` where `result(k) == mean(data((10*(k-1)+1):10*k)`? Makes sense, but it isn't what I normally think of as "binning"

Comment: What @DanBecker said, or do you want a 1000-element output that has applied the average on each successive 10-element subvector (i.e., an overlapping sliding window)?

Comment: Yes, "binning" means the following: [1 1 2 3 5 10]-> bin [0 4] with count 4 and bin [5 10] with count of 2. Can you please correct, Rajan?

Answer (score 2):

This should work, as long as the length of your vector is a multiple of 10:

```
data = rand(100,1);
result = mean(reshape(data, 10, length(data)/10),1)
```

If the length is not a multiple of 10, you'll need to decide what to do with the extra elements, and add some special case for that.

**Update**

Inspired by Rody's solution, the following will work on matrices of arbitrary dimension, as long as the first dimension is a multiple of 10:

```
data = rand(100,3,2);
sz = size(data);
result = squeeze(mean(reshape(data, [10 sz(1)/10 sz(2:end)]),1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
result = arrayfun(...
    @(x) mean(data(x:min(x+9,end),:),1), ...
    1:10:size(data,1), 'UniformOutput', false);
result = cat(1, result{:});
```

This one's a bit less sensitive to the exact number of rows in `data`. If there are only 6 rows left at the end, it will average those 6.

Comment: Why did you add the `,:` in `data(x:min(x+9,end),:)`? It doesn't seem to make any difference in the results.

Comment: I think you can simplify this down to `arrayfun(@(x) mean(data(x:min(x+9,end))),1:10:length(data))`, which will work for both column and row vectors.

Comment: @DanBecker try `data = rand(101,3);` and my answer will make more sense. The OP didn't mention his data was a *vector*, so I made my answer to work for the more general case; with matrices.

Comment: Ah, nice! I'll try get my reshape approach to support this too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `y=smooth(x,10)` or `y=filter(ones(1,10), 1, x)` and then use `y(1:10:end)` to select every 10th element.

Comment: `smooth(x,10)` is equivalent to `smooth(x,9)`, so that doesn't work. For your `filter` idea to work you need to use `y=filter(ones(1,10), 10, data)` and `y(10:10:end)`